# Is it right to say that setter function for property in python is like overloading the assignment operator?

Tags: python

I just started to study the subject of OOP in python and and I got into a bit of trouble subject of decorators/properties and all "private" methods tricks in python..

Is it okay to say that when using **@property** is like using an attribute, but behind the scenes there is a function that do something? (for example, checks the input)
In addition, is using the **@is_barking.setter** is like overloading the assignment operator in other languages (let's say C++)? because i can also check the input and things like that

This is the code:

```py
class Dog():
    def __init__(self,name):
        self.name = name

    @property
    def is_barking(self):
        try:
            return self._is_barking
        except AttributeError as error:
            self._is_barking = False
            return self._is_barking

    @is_barking.setter
    def is_barking(self,value):
        self._is_barking = value


def main():
    rexi = Dog("rexi")
    print(rexi.is_barking)
    rexi.is_barking = True
    print(rexi.is_barking)

main()

>> False
>> True
```

Thank you very much!

Comment: Yes, that's what a setter does, intercept attribute assignment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that's *sort of* correct. The setter lets you intercept assignment *to that attribute name alone*.

It doesn't overload assignment, it is simply facilitated for by the [descriptor protocol](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/descriptor.html) at runtime, and `property` objects are *data* descriptor objects; they get to intercept all attribute access (getting, setting and deleting) on instances of the class they are a member of, and so can veto any of those operations. This is different from C++ assignment overloading, which is handled at compile time (IIRC) and operates on whole instances, not just attributes on instances.

What really happens is that attribute assignment is handled by the class object whose instance the attribute is being assigned to, in the [`object.__setattr__` special method](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__setattr__). The class will check if the given attribute name is covered by an object *on the class* that is a descriptor object with a [`__set__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__set__) or [`__delete__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__delete__) method.

So *general* attribute assignment can be hooked into via the `__setattr__` special method, Python delegates attribute setting to the parent type of instances:

```
# foo.attr = bar   -> Python essentially calls __setattr__ on the class 
type(foo).__setattr__(foo, "attr", bar)
```

and in the regular, simple case that then becomes

```
foo.__dict__["attr"] = bar
```

but in reality, there is a search for a data descriptor *first*, on `type(foo)` and its parent classes. If such an object exist, then *it* is tasked with handling attribute setting:

```
obj = None
for cls in reversed(type(foo).__mro__):
    if "attr" in cls.__dict__:
        obj = cls.__dict__["attr"]
        break
if hasattr(obj, "__set__") or hasattr(obj, "__delete__"):  # data descriptor?
    try:
        obj.__set__(foo, bar)
    except AttributeError:
        raise AttributeError("can't set attribute")
else:
    foo.__dict__["attr"] = bar
```

`property` objects implement `__set__`, and this implementation will call your setter (if one is set).

Comment: Bro i think the answer is a little bit above my level in python LOL.
But thanks anyway, i will continue to learn and hope I get to this level :)

Comment: @Ba2sik: Don't worry, at *some point* you'll wonder why you can't set `instance.__dict__["propertyname"]` and have it show up, and then you'll remember this answer, and learn about data descriptors all over again. :-)